# Let the pair $(X, Y)$ have the bivariate normal distribution. Show that $aX + bY$ has a univariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let the pair $(X, Y)$ have the bivariate normal distribution of (6.76), and let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.
Show that $aX + bY$ has a univariate normal distribution, possibly with zero variance.

$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}Q(x,y)} \text{ for } x,y \in \mathbb{R}, \tag{6.76} $$

where

$$Q(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}\left[\left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1} \right)^2-2\rho \left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right) \left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right) + \left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2 \right]$$ for $\mu_1,\mu_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma_1,\sigma_2 >0, -1<\rho<1$.

I have no idea how to do this problem. I was thinking maybe trying to split $g(x,y)$ into separate marginal density functions but that math seems way too complicated considering what $g$ is.

Comment: characteristic function

Comment: Preliminary thoughts:
$$
\begin{align}
& \left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1} \right)^2-2\rho \left(\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right) \left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right) + \left(\frac{y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\right)^2 \\ {} \\
= {} & u^2 - 2\rho uv + v^2 = {} \underbrace{\, \Big( u^2 - 2\rho uv + \rho^2 v^2 \Big) + v^2 - \rho^2  v^2 \, }_\text{completing the square} \\ {} \\
= {} & \Big( u - \rho v\Big)^2 + (1-\rho^2) v^2 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Housefire This is a common definition of Gaussian multivariate.

Answer (score 0):

We do the following reversible transformation on the random vector
$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}
U \\
Y
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
X \\
Y
\end{array}\right] 
$$
where require
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{array}\right|=a^{2}+b^{2} \neq 0
$$
This means $a$ and $b$ are not zero at the same time. Now what we know is the PDF of  random vector $\left[\begin{array}{l}
X \\
Y
\end{array}\right] $
,that is $g(x,y)$ as mentioned above.
Then we can get the PDF of  random vector $\left[\begin{array}{l}
U \\
V
\end{array}\right] $ , denote it by $q(u,v)$.
Note the Jacobi Determinant $|J| = \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}$. To simplify the result, without the generality, we can assume $a = \cos\alpha, b=\sin\alpha$ where $0\le\alpha\le2\pi$ , after compulation, we can get the following fomular
$$
\begin{aligned}
q(u, v) &=g(u \cos \alpha-v \sin \alpha, u \sin \alpha+v \cos \alpha) \\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2} \sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}} \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2\left(1-\rho^{2}\right)}\left(A u^{2}-2 B u v+C v^{2}\right)\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\begin{array}{l}
A=\frac{\cos ^{2} \alpha}{\sigma_{1}^{2}}-2 \rho \frac{\cos \alpha \sin \alpha}{\sigma_{1} \sigma_{2}}+\frac{\sin ^{2} \alpha}{\sigma_{2}^{2}} \\
B=\frac{\cos \alpha \sin \alpha}{\sigma_{1}^{2}}-\rho \frac{\sin ^{2} \alpha-\cos ^{2} \alpha}{\sigma_{1} \sigma_{2}}-\frac{\cos \alpha \sin \alpha}{\sigma_{2}^{2}} \\
C=\frac{\sin ^{2} \alpha}{\sigma_{1}^{2}}+2 \rho \frac{\cos \alpha \sin \alpha}{\sigma_{1} \sigma_{2}}+\frac{\cos ^{2} \alpha}{\sigma_{2}^{2}}
\end{array}
$$
Now we get the following conclusion:

**1. The random vector obtained by the coordinate rotation transformation of the two-dimensional normal vector still obeys the normal distribution**.

Now what we want to know is the PDF of random variable $U = aX+bY$ which is just Marginal probability density function of $g(x,y)$ , the Join Probability Density Fuction

There is another conclusion about Normal Distribution as following.

**2. The marginal distribution of the bivariate normal distribution is still the normal distribution**

That what we just want to get!!!

Hope my answer can help you!!!