# Prove $\bar{X}$ and $X_i-\bar{X}$ are independent if $X_i's$ are independently normally distributed

Tags: statistics, independence, covariance

The statement comes from the book [statistics and data analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076669/let-the-pair-x-y-have-the-bivariate-normal-distribution-show-that-ax-by?rq=1) page 179, and I just wonder how to prove that $\bar{X}$ and $X_i-\bar{X}$ are independent if $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{Cov(\bar{X},X_i-\bar{X})=0}$ <s>and</s> $X_i's$ are independently normally distributed.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921127/how-do-you-prove-cov-left-barx-x-i-barx-right-0?rq=1) what you're looking for?This may require $X_i$ to be i.i.d however.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to prove rigorously that they are independent given zero covariance. And yes I left out the details that $X_i$ is i.i.d normally distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: In this answer I'll only consider standard normal $X_i$s, since it's no harder to do when they have other means and variances)

One way of doing this is with moment generating functions.
For a bivariate random variable $Z = (Z_1, Z_2)$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent if and only if the moment generating function $M_Z(\mathbf{s}) = \mathbf{E} e^{\mathbf{s}^T Z}$ factors into a product of a functions of $s_1$ and $s_2$ only, where $\mathbf{s} = (s_1, s_2)$.

Now, the thing to notice is that $(\bar{X}, X_i - \bar{X})$ is a linear transformation of the whole sample $X = (X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$.
Namely,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\bar{X} \\ X_i - \bar{X}\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{1}^T/n \\ e_i^T - \mathbf{1}^T/n\end{pmatrix} X
:= H X
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all $1$s and $e_i$ is the vector of all $0$s with a $1$ in the $i$th entry.

We can use this to write down the MGF:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} \exp\biggl\{\mathbf{s}^T \begin{pmatrix}\bar{X} \\ X_i - \bar{X}\end{pmatrix}\biggr\}
= \mathbf{E} \exp\{\mathbf{s}^T H X\} 
= \mathbf{E} \exp\{(H^T\mathbf{s})^T X\} 
\end{align*}

Then we can use the known moment generating function of a vector of iid normals ($\mathbf{E} e^{\mathbf{t}^T X} = \exp\{\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}^T \mathbf{t}\}$) to conclude that
$$
\mathbf{E} \exp\{(H^T\mathbf{s})^T X\} 
= \exp\{\frac{1}{2}(H^T\mathbf{s})^T(H^T\mathbf{s})\}
= \exp\{\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{s}^T HH^T \mathbf{s}\}.
$$

Now, we can multiply
\begin{align*}
HH^T
&= \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{1}^T/n \\ e_i^T - \mathbf{1}^T/n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{1}/n , & e_i - \mathbf{1}/n\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}^T/n \mathbf{1}/n & \mathbf{1}^T/n (e_i - \mathbf{1}/n) \\
(e_i - \mathbf{1}/n)^T \mathbf{1}/n & (e_i - \mathbf{1}/n)^T(e_i - \mathbf{1}/n)
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
1/n & 0 \\
0 & 1 - 1/n
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
so that the MGF becomes
$$
\exp\biggl\{\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{s}^T HH^T \mathbf{s}\biggr\}
= \exp\biggl\{\frac{1}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}s_1^2 + \frac{n-1}{n}s_2^2\biggr)\biggr\}
= e^{\frac{1}{2n}s_1^2} e^{\frac{n-1}{2n} s_2^2}.
$$

Since this factors into terms containing only $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively, we conlcude that $\bar{X}$ and $X_i - \bar{X}$ are independent (and also that they have $N(0, 1/n)$ and $N(0, 1 - 1/n)$ distributions respectively).

Comment: This is really a Perfect answer! Thanks very much!